# Link array values to other array and push to new array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to loop through an array of integer and sort of "link/map" each value to an image URL stored in another array (and then push the new data into a new array).

What I've tried is using a For loop with the indexOf method, but doesn't really seems to work.

Also, it's important to note that I don't have a single occurrence of data in my `arrayOfInteger`, I need to link each value to its image equivalent.

Here's my code snippet:

```
var images = [];

var arrayOfInteger = [1, 16, 10, 8, 13, 9, 19, 12, 5, 18, 9, 1, 17, 7, 18, 16, 9, 5, 19, 10, 0, 13, 3, 2, 12];

var imgData = [
        [0, 'img/0.svg'],
        [1, 'img/1.svg'],
        [2, 'img/2.svg'],
        [3, 'img/3.svg'],
        [4, 'img/4.svg'],
        [5, 'img/5.svg'],
        [6, 'img/6.svg'],
        [7, 'img/7.svg'],
        [8, 'img/8.svg'],
        [10, 'img/10.svg'],
        [11, 'img/11.svg'],
        [12, 'img/12.svg'],
        [13, 'img/13.svg'],
        [15, 'img/15.svg'],
        [16, 'img/16.svg'],
        [17, 'img/17.svg'],
        [18, 'img/18.svg'],
        [19, 'img/19.svg'],
    ]

 function pushImages() {
        for(var i=0;i<arrayOfInteger.length;i++){
             if(imgData.indexOf(grades[i])!= -1){images.push(imgData[i][1]);}
          }
    }
```

I'm also wondering... Am I using the good method to achieve what I want ?

#### EDIT:

In the end, I want `images` array to have these urls (based on the integer value from `arrayOfInteger`):

```
images = ['img/1.svg', 'img/16.svg', 'img/10.svg', 'img/8.svg', 'img/13.svg', 'img/9.svg', 'img/19.svg', 'img/12.svg', 'img/5.svg', 'img/18.svg', 'img/9.svg', 'img/1.svg', 'img/17.svg', 'img/7.svg', 'img/18.svg', 'img/16.svg', 'img/9.svg', 'img/5.svg', 'img/19.svg', 'img/10.svg', 'img/0.svg', 'img/13.svg', 'img/3.svg', 'img/2.svg', 'img/12.svg']
```

Because I want to show images in my interface based on what `arrayOfInteger` is giving me. This array is updated from a server frequently.

Comment: What is `grades`?

Comment: why dont you use array of object instead of array of arrays? and what do the variable “grades” refers to?

Comment: Start by clicking the `<>` in the editor, add the JS and make it run. For example you did not have any `grades` in your code

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? This seems like a lot of code that can easily be compressed to less than 5 lines. For example, if you have an index `i`, the file name is just `img = 'img/' + i + '.svg'`. Now your entire array of arrays can be calculated in just one line of code instead of typed out with 20 lines.

Comment: Does the output have to be ordered the same way? If you start by sorting the array of indexes, then you can write a neat O(nlogn) solution instead of the O(n*m) below

Comment: @Walk, @mplungjan, oups, for the sake of the example i did change my `grades` variable name for `arrayOfInteger`...

Comment: @JoeFrambach You can even skip the sorting and just loop from 0 to 19.

Comment: @JoeFrambach, Yes, it's really important that the output is ordered in the same way.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, this is exactly why I asked on Stackoverflow.. i wasn't sure if I could optimise my code here .. ahha But in the end, I need to show images in my interface based on the integer I get from an API (the API data is stored in my `arrayOfInteger`.)

Comment: please add an exampel of the wanted result.

Comment: @NinaScholz, I'll edit my question with an example.

Comment: @SimonDuchaine, thank you for the update, is the interger numer kind og related to the image number, or is it just a coincidence without meaning?

Comment: @NinaScholz It's only a coincidence as I wanted to use the same image name as my integer possibilities to simplify everything ..

Comment: I think using the object method will be a better choice for future expansions. say for example if you are completely skipping the 3rd image in future., then array indexes will not be a better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only answer here that works with your data - with minimal modification!

```
function pushImages() {
    // Clear images if preferred
    images = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfInteger.length; i++){
        var data = imgData.find(function (data) {
            return data[0] == arrayOfInteger[i]
        });
        if (data) { images.push(data[1]); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hum. It works but the problem I get now is that my `images` array seems to populate indefinitely (as the source array `arrayOfInteger` is updating its value every 2 seconds or so). My source array is of 25 elements, and I would think my `images` array would still be of 25. It's like if every time `pushImages` get called, data is appended to the existing array. What if I would want not to exceed 25 elements?

Comment: I mean replace new data in `images` if `arrayOfInteger` values change and `pushImages()` is run multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var images = [];
var arrayOfInteger = [1, 16, 10, 8, 13, 9, 19, 12, 5, 18, 9, 1, 17, 7, 18, 16, 9, 5, 19, 10, 0, 13, 3, 2, 12];
var imgData = {
    0 : 'img/0.svg',
    1 : 'img/1.svg',
    2 : 'img/2.svg',
    3 : 'img/3.svg',
    4 : 'img/4.svg',
    5 : 'img/5.svg',
    6 : 'img/6.svg',
    7 : 'img/7.svg',
    8 : 'img/8.svg',
    10 : 'img/10.svg',
    11 : 'img/11.svg',
    12 : 'img/12.svg',
    13 : 'img/13.svg',
    15 : 'img/15.svg',
    16 : 'img/16.svg',
    17 : 'img/17.svg',
    18 : 'img/18.svg',
    19 : 'img/19.svg'
};
function pushImages () {
    arrayOfInteger.forEach(function (v, i) {
        if (typeof imgData[v] === 'object') images.push(imgData[v]);
    });
}
```

are you looking for something like this??

Comment: Why use an object? Just create a single array with the file names.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice that looks good. forgot about that.. thankyou for reminding.

Comment: You can even take it a step further and get rid of the array completely since you can calculate the paths in a loop just from the index.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I doubt the path strings are the actual values. It's common for people to anonymize their code here.

Comment: I interpret the given data as representative of the real data in that there is a pattern in the data, even if these are not the exact strings in the final code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice : I think I would go with the first answer itself, as there can be missing indexes for the mapping array.

Comment: @AdarshMohan Which array do you refer to as "the mapping array"?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice arrayOfIntegers

Answer (score -2):

Your entire example can be reduced significantly:

```
for(var i=0; i < arrayOfInteger.length; i++){
    var imgData = 'img/' + arrayOfInteger[i] + '.svg'
}
```

Note that the only array here is `arrayOfInteger`. The `imgData` array is completely unnecessary. When you see such repetition, you should always look for ways to reduce the amount of typing or copy/pasting you have to do.

Comment: what if the image name becomes different?? something like “1.svg” for 2nd data?

Comment: I think that this method could also work for me. Gonna try this out.

Answer (score -4):

With underscore:

```
var images = [];
var arrayOfInteger = [1, 16, 10, 8, 13, 9, 19, 12, 5, 18, 9, 1, 17, 7, 18, 16, 9, 5, 19, 10, 0, 13, 3, 2, 12];
var imgData = [
    [0, 'img/0.svg'],
    [1, 'img/1.svg'],
    [2, 'img/2.svg'],
    [3, 'img/3.svg'],
    [4, 'img/4.svg'],
    [5, 'img/5.svg'],
    [6, 'img/6.svg'],
    [7, 'img/7.svg'],
    [8, 'img/8.svg'],
    [10, 'img/10.svg'],
    [11, 'img/11.svg'],
    [12, 'img/12.svg'],
    [13, 'img/13.svg'],
    [15, 'img/15.svg'],
    [16, 'img/16.svg'],
    [17, 'img/17.svg'],
    [18, 'img/18.svg'],
    [19, 'img/19.svg'],
]
_.each(imgData, function(t){
   var o = _.indexOf(arrayOfInteger, t[0]);
   if (o != -1) {
        images.push(t[1]);
   }
});
```

Comment: What do we gain by using underscore here aside from the latency hit?

Comment: Can you explain further how this solves the OP's question?

Comment: Well, about underscore library, is just for avoid the "for" structure. And if He is looking for  exist images then I think is better take them. So can exists only 5 images and an array of 20 items, It only will go  2 times.